# MySQL joining tables group by sum issue

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

I have problem with joining tables, here are example tables:

Table A: ( 30 rows)

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ Name       ║ Description ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Type       ║ Unicode Art ║
║ 2  ║ Header     ║ Spreadsheet ║
║ 3  ║ Auto Align ║ Off         ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Table B: ( 100 rows )

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║ Name       ║ Description ║ TableA  ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 1  ║ Type       ║ Unicode Art ║ 1       ║
║ 2  ║ Header     ║ Spreadsheet ║ 1       ║
║ 3  ║ Auto Align ║ Off         ║ 2       ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╝
```

Table C: ( 8000 rows )

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║ Article    ║ Text        ║ TableB  ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 1  ║ Type       ║ Unicode Art ║ 1       ║
║ 2  ║ Header     ║ Spreadsheet ║ 1       ║
║ 3  ║ Auto Align ║ Off         ║ 2       ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╝
```

Table D: ( 100 000 rows and counting )

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║ Date      ║ Clicks     ║ Impressions ║ TableC  ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 1  ║ 20120814  ║ 10         ║ 3           ║ 1       ║
║ 2  ║ 20120815  ║ 13         ║ 5           ║ 1       ║
║ 3  ║ 20120816  ║ 15         ║ 10          ║ 2       ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╝
```

Table E: ( 200 000 rows and counting )

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║ Date      ║ Views      ║ Visitors  ║ TableC  ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 1  ║ 20120814  ║ 10         ║ 3         ║ 1       ║
║ 2  ║ 20120815  ║ 13         ║ 5         ║ 1       ║
║ 3  ║ 20120816  ║ 15         ║ 10        ║ 2       ║
║ 4  ║ 20120817  ║ 8          ║ 7         ║ 2       ║
║ 5  ║ 20120818  ║ 9          ║ 4         ║ 2       ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

I query this tables with single sql statement:

```
SELECT
       A.name,
       A.Description,
       SUM(D.clicks),
       SUM(D.Impressions),
       SUM(E.Views),
       SUM(E.Visitors)
FROM 
       A 
       LEFT JOIN B
         ON A.ID=B.TableA
       LEFT JOIN C
         ON B.ID=C.TableB
       LEFT JOIN D
         ON C.ID=D.TableC
       LEFT JOIN E
         ON C.ID=E.TableC
GROUP BY
       A.ID
```

Problem is that the query returns invalid SUM for Table D and Table E
However if query Table D and Table E in invidual queries I get right values:

```
SELECT
       A.name,
       A.Description,
       SUM(D.clicks),
       SUM(D.Impressions)
FROM 
       A 
       LEFT JOIN B
         ON A.ID=B.TableA
       LEFT JOIN C
         ON B.ID=C.TableB
       LEFT JOIN D
         ON C.ID=D.TableC
GROUP BY
       A.ID
```

EDIT 1:
I have tried RIGHT JOIN, JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN none of them worked,
ofcourse it's possible that I used those in wrong places.
But in the first statement where I got "all included" values are multiplied
many thousand times higher than they really are.

Comment: Haven't read your question, but +1 for the table art.

Comment: How is B related to A? Likewise with C to B?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to flatten both D and E table. Then I suppose A and B are mere lookups for C, so there's no need to do GROUP BY on A: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fccf1/8

I removed the noise(A and B), as I can't see(yet) how A and B are related to summarizing the information for C

Try this:

```
SELECT
       C.Article,
       C.Text,

       COALESCE(D.ClicksSum,0) AS ClicksSum,
       COALESCE(D.ImpressionsSum,0) AS ImpressionsSum,

       COALESCE(E.ViewsSum,0) AS ViewsSum,
       COALESCE(E.VisitorsSum,0) AS VisitorsSum
FROM 
       C

       LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT TableC, SUM(Clicks) AS ClicksSum, SUM(Impressions) AS ImpressionsSum
         FROM D
         GROUP BY TableC
       ) D ON C.ID=D.TableC

       LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT TableC, SUM(Views) AS ViewsSum, SUM(Visitors) AS VisitorsSum
         FROM E
         GROUP BY TableC       
       ) E ON C.ID=E.TableC
```

Output:

```
|    ARTICLE |        TEXT | CLICKSSUM | IMPRESSIONSSUM | VIEWSSUM | VISITORSSUM |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Type | Unicode Art |        23 |              8 |       23 |           8 |
|     Header | Spreadsheet |        15 |             10 |       32 |          21 |
| Auto Align |         Off |         0 |              0 |        0 |           0 |
```

Note that I didn't type those schema in my sqlfiddle post manually, I uses sqlfiddle's **Text to DDL**

I love http://sqlfiddle.com, its **Text to DDL** can even parses out the data from your ASCII art ツ

---

Upon seeing your clearer objective(from your comment), this might be it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fccf1/13

```
SELECT
       A.Name, A.Description,

       COALESCE(SUM(D.ClicksSum),0) AS ClicksSum,
       COALESCE(SUM(D.ImpressionsSum),0) AS ImpressionsSum,

       COALESCE(SUM(E.ViewsSum),0) AS ViewsSum,
       COALESCE(SUM(E.VisitorsSum),0) AS VisitorsSum
FROM 
       C

       LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT TableC, SUM(Clicks) AS ClicksSum, SUM(Impressions) AS ImpressionsSum
         FROM D
         GROUP BY TableC
       ) D ON C.ID=D.TableC

       LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT TableC, SUM(Views) AS ViewsSum, SUM(Visitors) AS VisitorsSum
         FROM E
         GROUP BY TableC       
       ) E ON C.ID=E.TableC

       RIGHT JOIN B ON B.ID = C.TableB
       RIGHT JOIN A ON A.ID = B.TableA

GROUP BY A.ID
```

Output:

```
|       NAME | DESCRIPTION | CLICKSSUM | IMPRESSIONSSUM | VIEWSSUM | VISITORSSUM |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Type | Unicode Art |        38 |             18 |       55 |          29 |
|     Header | Spreadsheet |         0 |              0 |        0 |           0 |
| Auto Align |         Off |         0 |              0 |        0 |           0 |
```

---

The above approach might still produce cartesian products, flatten the SubCategory(B) before grouping it to Category(A):  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fccf1/19

```
SELECT 
  A.Name, A.Description,
  COALESCE(SUM(B.ClicksSum),0) AS ClicksSum,
  COALESCE(SUM(B.ImpressionsSum),0) AS ImpressionsSum,
  COALESCE(SUM(B.ViewsSum),0) AS ViewsSum,
  COALESCE(SUM(B.VisitorsSum),0) AS VisitorsSum
FROM A
LEFT JOIN
(

  SELECT 
    B.ID, B.TableA,
    SUM(C.ClicksSum) AS ClicksSum,
    SUM(C.ImpressionsSum) AS ImpressionsSum,
    SUM(C.ViewsSum) AS ViewsSum,
    SUM(C.VisitorsSum) AS VisitorsSum
  FROM B
  LEFT JOIN
  (

    SELECT
      C.TableB,

      D.ClicksSum,
      D.ImpressionsSum,

      E.ViewsSum,
      E.VisitorsSum
    FROM 
    C

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT TableC, SUM(Clicks) AS ClicksSum, SUM(Impressions) AS ImpressionsSum
      FROM D
      GROUP BY TableC
    ) D ON C.ID=D.TableC

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT TableC, SUM(Views) AS ViewsSum, SUM(Visitors) AS VisitorsSum
      FROM E
      GROUP BY TableC       
    ) E ON C.ID=E.TableC

  ) C ON C.TableB = B.ID
  GROUP BY B.ID

) B ON B.TableA = A.ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Output:

```
|       NAME | DESCRIPTION | CLICKSSUM | IMPRESSIONSSUM | VIEWSSUM | VISITORSSUM |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Type | Unicode Art |        38 |             18 |       55 |          29 |
|     Header | Spreadsheet |         0 |              0 |        0 |           0 |
| Auto Align |         Off |         0 |              0 |        0 |           0 |
```

Comment: You can think Table A as Category, Table B as SubCategory, Table C as Product, Table D as Product advertising data "ad stats", Table E as Product visiting data "includes all visits". I need to summarize how each category is doing

Comment: Thank you got it working with revision 2 :) BTW might want to add missing AS in case someone reads and uses this after this. Rev2 missing AS ImpressionsSum
So as I'm talking about revisions, in which situation might r2 vs r3 be problematic. I'm using php so doesn't really matter how long the statement is. Don't need the remember by memory :)

Comment: Welcome :-) Overlooked, added the `AS` now

Answer (score 1):

Both table D and table E are linked to the rest by table C. So your first query gives a cartesian product of all rows in table D times all rows in table E, and the SUM function aggregates this cartesian product. Probably you will have to group by table C as well, not only by table A.

Comment: I thought of that too, but then query return table A values as many times as there are data for Table A in Table C and counts sum invidually for each Table C value. Leaving me options like subquery? Anything else?