# How can I join 3 tables and calculate the correct sum of fields from 2 tables, without duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables A, B, C. Table A is linked to B, and table A is linked to C. I want to join the 3 tables and find the sum of B.cost and the sum of C.clicks. However, it is not giving me the expected value, and when I select everything without the group by, it is showing duplicate rows. I am expecting the row values from B to roll up into a single sum, and the row values from C to roll up into a single sum.

My query looks like

```
select A.*, sum(B.cost), sum(C.clicks) from A 
join B
left join C
group by A.id
having sum(cost) > 10
```

I tried to group by `B.a_id` and `C.another_field_in_a` also, but that didn't work.

Here is a DB fiddle with all of the data and the full query:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/768745/13

Notice how the sum fields are greater than the sum of the individual tables? I'm expecting the sums to be equal, containing only the rows of the table B and C once. I also tried adding `distinct` but that didn't help.

I'm using Postgres. (The fiddle is set to MySQL though.) Ultimately I will want to use a `having` clause to select the rows according to their sums. This query will be for millions of rows.

Comment: Please post the full query in the actual question.  Your watered down version does not convey the same thing as the original.

Comment: So you want 26 in sum(cost) and 29 in sum(clicks).  Can you add the expected output.

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement but check here [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/768745/7)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The full query is posted in the fiddle.

Comment: @VR46 I need the query to work with millions of rows. The `and ad_group_keyword_id = 1210802` will not be there and is only for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this ([MySQL joining tables group by sum issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026182/mysql-joining-tables-group-by-sum-issue)) and created a query like this

```
select * 
from A
join (select B.a_id, sum(B.cost) as cost 
  from B 
  group by B.a_id) B on A.id = B.a_id
left join (select C.keyword_id, sum(C.clicks) as clicks
  from C
  group by C.keyword_id) C on A.keyword_id = C.keyword_id
group by A.id
having sum(cost) > 10
```

I don't know if it's efficient though. I don't know if it's more or less efficient than Gordon's. I ran both queries and this one seemed faster, 27s vs. 2m35s. Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c61c74/10

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the logic correctly, the problem is the Cartesian product caused by the two joins.  Your query is a bit hard to follow, but I think the intent is better handled with correlated subqueries:

```
select k.*,
       (select sum(cost)
        from ad_group_keyword_network n
        where n.event_date >= '2015-12-27' and
              n.ad_group_keyword_id = 1210802 and
              k.id = n.ad_group_keyword_id
       ) as cost,
       (select sum(clicks)
        from keyword_click c
        where (c.date is null or c.date >= '2015-12-27') and
              k.keyword_id = c.keyword_id               
       ) as clicks
from ad_group_keyword k
where k.status = 2 ;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/768745/12) is the corresponding SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

The subselect should be faster than the `group by` on the unaggregated data.  However, you need the right indexes:  `ad_group_keyword_network(ad_group_keyword_id, ad_group_keyword_id, event_date, cost)` and `keyword_click(keyword_id, date, clicks)`.

Comment: Are you sure sub-selects would be efficient? The tables will have millions of rows. I used to love sub-queries, but I found them a bit slow. I tried to run it and it took over a minute.

Comment: Yes, it is a Cartesian product problem. I thought since I grouped by the field in the first table, it would collapse the other tables?

Answer (score 1):

Simply split the aggregate of the second table into a subquery as follows:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/768745/27

```
select ad_group_keyword.*, SumCost, sum(keyword_click.clicks) 
from ad_group_keyword 
left join keyword_click on ad_group_keyword.keyword_id = keyword_click.keyword_id 
left join (select ad_group_keyword.id, sum(cost) SumCost
           from ad_group_keyword join ad_group_keyword_network on ad_group_keyword.id = ad_group_keyword_network.ad_group_keyword_id
           where event_date >= '2015-12-27' 
           group by ad_group_keyword.id
           having sum(cost) > 20
) Cost on Cost.id=ad_group_keyword.id
where  
(keyword_click.date is null or keyword_click.date >= '2015-12-27') 
and status = 2 
group by ad_group_keyword.id
```