# How to Group Sum of a Join using POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, sum

Two Tables:
Table M with 3 columns - contains 100 records - HOUSEDATA

- House ID - 100 records
- Zipcode  - 100 records
- SquareFootage - 100 records

Table F with 2 columns - Contains 10 records - ZIPCODEDATA

- UniqueZipcodes - 10 records
- TotalSquareFootage - 0 records

I would like to join these two tables and sum the total squarefootage by each zipcode.
When I run the following UPDATE, it aggregates all zipcodes into each row and shows the total of all zipcodes in each of the 10 rows in table F.

````
SET TOTALSQUAREFOOTAGE = F.VALSUM
FROM HOUSEDATA AS M
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ZIPCODEDATA.UNIQUEZipcode,
            SUM(SQUAREFOOTAGE) VALSUM
            FROM ZIPCODEDATA
            GROUP BY UNIQUEZipcode) F ON M.Zipcode = F.UNIQUEZipcode```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I join 3 tables and calculate the correct sum of fields from 2 tables, without duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712782/how-can-i-join-3-tables-and-calculate-the-correct-sum-of-fields-from-2-tables-w)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    F.UNIQUEZipcode,
    SUM(SQUAREFOOTAGE) VALSUM 
FROM ZIPCODEDATA F
LEFT JOIN HOUSEDATA M ON (M.Zipcode = F.UNIQUEZipcode)
GROUP BY F.UNIQUEZipcode
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.